# Only echo out sertain thing based on if-statement in PHP

Tags: php

I want to only echo a certain part out, if a variable is 1.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    echo 'Hi John' .
    if($lnameCheck == 1) {
        ' Doe'
    }
    . '. How is it going?';
?>
```

Is this possible, **without** doing this:

```
<?php
    if($lnameCheck == 0) {
        echo 'Hi John Doe. How is it going?';
    }
    if($lnameCheck == 1) {
        echo 'Hi John. How is it going?';
    }
?>
```

I don't want to do this, because it is really bad code, especially when I start to add more than one variable.

Comment: This first example is really bad code because it does not work. Set priorities when you raise the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a shorter working code then you can try this.

```
<?php  echo 'Hi John' . ($lnameCheck ? ' Doe' : '') . '. How is it going?'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you just want to add something to the name(in this case) it may be better to have a variable with the value (`John`) and add onto it the second part if the test passes.  You then echo out the resultant variable in the sentence...

```
$name = "John";
if($lnameCheck == 0) {
    $name .= " Doe";
}
echo "Hi $name. How is it going?";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use associative array to hold variable value something like

```php
<?php
$lnameCheck = 1; // for example


$posName = [1 => " Doe", 2 => "Whatever"]; // Or just array
$name_var = array_key_exists($lnameCheck, $posName) ? $posName[$lnameCheck] : "";
echo "Hi John$name_var. How is it going?";
?>
```